# Using detail to delivery API's

Tags: oracle, api

I created this procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE APPS.test_dlv3
IS
BEGIN
DECLARE

-- STANDARD PARAMETERS.
 pApiVersion    NUMBER := 1.0;
 pInitMsgList   VARCHAR2(30);
 pCommit        VARCHAR2(30);

-- PARAMETERS FOR WSH_DELIVERY_DETAILS_PUB.DETAIL_TO_DELIVERY
 pDeliveryId    NUMBER;
 pDeliveryName  VARCHAR2(30);
 pTabOfDelDet   WSH_DELIVERY_DETAILS_PUB.id_tab_type;
 pAction        VARCHAR2(30);

-- OUT PARAMETERS
 xReturnStatus  VARCHAR2(10);
 xMsgCount      NUMBER;
 xMsgData       VARCHAR2(2000);
 xMsgDetails    VARCHAR2(3000);
 xMsgSummary    VARCHAR2(3000);

-- HANDLE EXCEPTIONS
 vFailApiException EXCEPTION;

BEGIN
-- INITIALIZE RETURN STATUS
 xReturnStatus := WSH_UTIL_CORE.G_RET_STS_SUCCESS;

-- CALL THIS PROCEDURE TO INITIALIZE APPLICATIONS PARAMETERS.
 FND_GLOBAL.APPS_INITIALIZE(
       user_id      => ,  --hide
       resp_id      => ,  --hide
       resp_appl_id => ); --hide

-- VALUES FOR WSH_DELIVERY_DETAILS_PUB.DETAIL_TO_DELIVERY
 pDeliveryId        := 379358;
 pDeliveryName      := 'Delivery01';
 pTabOfDelDet(1)    := 354601 ;
 pAction            := 'ASSIGN';

-- CALL TO WSH_DELIVERY_DETAILS_PUB.DETAIL_TO_DELIVERY.
 WSH_DELIVERY_DETAILS_PUB.detail_to_delivery( 
        p_api_version       => pApiVersion, 
        p_init_msg_list     => pInitMsgList,
        p_commit            => pCommit, 
        x_return_status     => xReturnStatus,
        x_msg_count         => xMsgCount,
        x_msg_data          => xMsgData,
        p_TabOfDelDets      => pTabOfDelDet,
        p_action            => pAction,
        p_delivery_id       => pDeliveryId,
        p_delivery_name     => pDeliveryName );

 IF (xReturnStatus <> WSH_UTIL_CORE.G_RET_STS_SUCCESS) THEN RAISE vFailApiException;

 ELSE DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Detail '||pTabOfDelDet(1)|| ' assignment to the delivery '|| pDeliveryName ||' is successful');

 END IF;

 Exception

   WHEN vFailApiException THEN WSH_UTIL_CORE.get_messages('Y', xMsgSummary, xMsgDetails, xMsgCount);

    IF xMsgCount > 1 THEN xMsgData := xMsgSummary || xMsgDetails;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Message Data : '||xMsgData);

    ELSE xMsgData := xMsgSummary;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Message Data : '||xMsgData);

    END IF;

END;        
END;
/
```

But the result is always like this :

```
Message Data : Error: Error in assigning one or more details to a delivery.
Warning: These entities can not be grouped together as their grouping attributes do not match.
```

Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each inventory organization that you ship from has Shipping Parameters defined in the Order Management/Shipping Execution setups.

One area of that form is "Delivery Grouping Attributes".  Some attributes are mandatory -- ship from and ship to.  Think about it -- if two order lines are being shipped from two different locations, they're not part of the same delivery (they can be part of the same *trip*, but that is a separate though related concept in Oracle Shipping Execution).

Anyway, if the organization you are shipping from has Shipping Parameters set up that specify a given attribute is part of the Delivery Grouping Attributes, then every delivery detail (~order line, sort of, but not always) you add to the delivery must match that attribute for the delivery.

For example, if "Ship Method" is a delivery grouping attribute and you try to add an order line shipped "Next Day Air" to a "LTL Truck" delivery, you'll get the error you are encountering.

Check the Shipping Parameters for the organizations from which you are shipping and then check the value of each Delivery Grouping Attribute to make sure they match between the delivery and the delivery detail you are attempting to assign to the delivery.